# Script for a button with Alert in Google spreadsheet after clicking which it redirects to a URL in new tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to add a Button in google spreadsheet which would redirect a user to a specific URL assigned in the script. This is the script I'm using:

```
function testNew() {
    showURL('Search Here','https://docs.google.com');
}
//


function showURL(name,url) {
    var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="parent" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(50).setWidth(200)
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO) ;
}

if (response = ui.Button.YES) {
    openURL(name,url)

}
else {
    Logger.log("You should have tried")
}
```

When I run this script and click on the Button, it says "**ui not detected**". When I remove this:

```
if (response = ui.Button.YES) {
    openURL(name,url)

}
else {
    Logger.log("You should have tried")
}
```

Then alert box works perfectly but when I click on "Yes", nothing really happens. It doesn't redirect me anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting "`ui not detected`", since you have written the below part **outside** the function `showURL`

```
if (response = ui.Button.YES){
  openURL(name,url)
}else {
  Logger.log("You should have tried")
}
```

And if you want to re-direct to different page, refer the below code.

```
function testNew(){
  showURL('Search Here','https://docs.google.com');
}

function showURL(name,url) {
    var html = '<html><body style="margin:0px;"><div class="modal-dialog-buttons"><a href="'+url+'" target="parent" onclick="google.script.host.close()"><button style="margin:5px;">Yes</button></a><button onclick="google.script.host.close()">No</button></div></body></html>';
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(50).setWidth(400)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Are you sre you want to contine?');
 }
```